read-only mode activated for me but seemingly it is not a maintenance thing
last night I was on Islam.stackexchange that I was suddenly logged-off by the site, and a bar appeared at the top saying:

This site is currently in read-only mode. We’ll return with full
functionality soon. Visit our status page or search our recent meta
posts on the topic for more info.

The status page linked above doesn't open for me. Also right now I saw the main page of Islam.stackexchange and find it quite active, so thought maybe it is a problem for me alone, and better to ask rather than to wait. Any clue?

https://shouldiblamecaching.com/

@testing-for-ya, I did nothing extra and after 2 hours from asking this Q everything is fine again, therefore, no reason to blame caching, ISP, or browser. Seemed a bug to me, as long as some staff will give a more acceptable answer.

Once upon a time, the Company would update DNS during maintenance to send web traffic to the DR data center in Colorado (aka "CO"), where the secondary/hot spare database is in read-only mode. The code is smart enough to recognize that the database is read-only, and presents that banner.
Recently, I believe they've configured that redirect-to-DR behavior to be automatic & handled by Cloudflare. I'm not sure what triggers that redirect to happen, but presumably some sort of health check / heartbeat from the web servers.
It could be there was a momentary problem and CF briefly sent traffic to CO, or maybe some issue with the health check, or some issue with a Cloudflare POP, or who knows...
In the past, you probably would have gotten a "Oops! Something Bad Happened!" page or similar error page. Now you get the read-only site, which directs users to the Status Page. Note that their Status page is manually maintained via their Incident Response application--so it'll only show outages if the team has responded to the issue and determined they need to put up a status page.

not sure if my question has had any effect, but it seemed like a bug as now after 2 hours that passed from asking the Q I checked and the website is now fine again (before that the problem persisted for almost a whole day), besides I'm automatically logged-in.

@testing-for-ya, actually I was engaged for several (say e.g. 15 or 20) hours, but two hours after submitting my Q here it was solved as strange as it appeared at the first place. I did nothing for it to be solved, and I had done nothing special for it to appear, so a mere simple guess that maybe my question was seen by those involved to find and resolve a bug. But maybe you are right as well, that it was a noise/blips, who knows? Maybe it was some bug due to a conflict in somewhere which didn't engage you (and others) in those >>2 hours.

@testing-for-ya, asked the question here to know why I feel to be the only person having this problem, as fast as I understood the website was active all the time I used to think it is under maintenance. Anyway, thank you for the time, maybe only the staff can explain it, if they will ... I don't care anymore as I am again active where I care more than here in meta :)
