Why is Stack Overflow showing in read-only mode?
I'm unable to login on Stack Overflow since today morning and there is no explanation given by them in any of their forums.




try clearing all your cookies and seeing if you can log in. Some folks on Ask ubuntu had the same issue.

You might have been hit by this bug: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399904/stack-overflow-in-read-only-mode-for-past-2-days

@EmilJeřábek most likely, yes. I voted to reopen that one.
