Login issue for Mathematics SE
I've a strange issue with my Mathematics SE profile.
Access to all sites (Mathematics, Philosophy, HSM) works well on the mobile.
Access to Philosophy and HSM is fine on my desktop with Google browser but I cannot load Mathematics SE: it asks me for Login and the result is:

What is wrong?

Possibly https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/399904/stack-overflow-in-read-only-mode-for-past-2-days

The issue has benn solved clearing the cache, as per linked post (my previous comemnt has been deleted by someone...). May I delete the question above?

I'm glad your problem was solved! You do not need to delete your question. It can serve as a helpful signpost to future visitors who have the same problem. The notice at the top of your question will point them towards the solution that helped you.
